# How could we use mpic++ as compiler for Xcode?

Tags: c++, boost, mpi

As I need to use mpic++ as a compiler of my c++ program (because I need to use BOOST_MOI), is there a way to achieve that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mpic++ is basically just a wrapper that automatically includes the MPI libraries when you compile and link your C++ program. In other words, you can compile your C++ code with mpic++ in exactly the same way as you'd do with say g++ or clang++ (assuming that you have installed MPI correctly).

Comment: What exactly is your problem? How do you attempt to compile and what is the error?